# Plot a country's chloropleth map using lat and lon columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, geopandas

I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude values. I can plot the points on a global map, however my requirements are to achieve something like this:

[image]

Code for current map:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_geo(data,lat=data['Y'],lon=data['X'])
fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

Current Map:

[image]

The data is from NICE, France. I can use any library or package but my data is only limited to lat and lon columns. I will be putting in the color on the map based on another column but for now just the map itself with the points and outline is needed. How do I achieve this?

Data Sample:

```
[[ 7.07406569, 43.63045404],
   [ 7.06488181, 43.61782587],
   [ 6.943076  , 43.653562  ],
   [ 6.927238  , 43.65362208],
   [ 7.092407  , 43.600197  ],
   [ 7.099427  , 43.632552  ]]
```

Comment: can you post your data? (partial at least)

Comment: Added. Hope it suffices

Comment: Oh. So what are you are trying to plot exactly, what sort of data? Nice boundaries? Surely you can find those on Github.

Comment: I tried but all the examples include some sort of json file which I don't have. I just want a Nice map with boundaries and the points plotted within it. Basically instead my current global map, I want a nice map.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-geopandas-data-frames

Comment: If you add `fitbounds='locations'` to `px.scatter_geo()` you will get a map zoomed in on your points.

Comment: @MohammadHaris there's no way to just magically make your points into regional shapes. You do need to find a shapefile/geoJSON/etc you'd like to plot with, aggregate your point-wise data to these polygons, and then plot the polygons. the image you posted is very fuzzy, but maybe you're talking about admin1 (state/province) data? [natural earth's 50m:1 admin1 boundaries](//www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Once you've downloaded this, you can assign your points to geometries with [`geopandas.sjoin`](//geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html), then plot them using [geopandas' plotting tools](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's go through it step by step.
First, get the geojson for the area. We find that courtesy of https://github.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson. We get the Alpes Maritimes area, we isolate Nice area from it (Nice-1 to Nice-9), and we generate some dummy data for it, in a new dataframe. We merge dataframes on name column, and we plot it:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import json

with open('cantons-06-alpes-maritimes.geojson') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
alpes_maritimes_data = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data['features'])
nice_df = alpes_maritimes_data[14:22]
df_list = [('Nice-1', 72), ('Nice-2', 112), ('Nice-3', 44), ('Nice-5', 2345), ('Nice-6', 99)]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['Name', 'Data'])
merged_df = nice_df.merge(data_df, how='left', left_on='nom', right_on='Name').set_index("Name").fillna(0)
fig = px.choropleth(merged_df,
                      geojson=merged_df.geometry,
                      locations=merged_df.index, color="Data",
                    range_color=(merged_df["Data"].min(), merged_df["Data"].max()),
                    title = 'Nice, France'
                   
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":50,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

And we get our choropleth map:

[image]